# Storing large JSONB files in Postgres with JDBC

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, jsonb

We're considering using Scala to store some large JSON documents (about 500MB in size) in a JSONB column of a Postgres table.  I've written some Scala code that looks like the below to write the data into the database.  However, the insert is having some problems (the exception thrown is apparently too large for the statement proxy to handle, so it's just an OutOfMemoryException).  Is there a better way for me to insert such large files?  I've tried inserting the JSONB column as a `PGobject` and as an `InputStream`.

```
implicit val conn = TransactionHelper.conn()

var pstmt: Option[PreparedStatement] = None
var rset: Option[ResultSet] = None
var id: Option[Long] = None

try {
  pstmt = Some(conn.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO configuration_record (configuration_id, state, config_info) VALUES (?, ?, encode(?, 'escape')::JSONB)"
  ))

  val bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonData.getBytes())

  pstmt.get.setString(1, configurationId)
  pstmt.get.setString(2, "Begin")
  pstmt.get.setBinaryStream(3, bais, jsonData.getBytes().length)

  pstmt.get.executeUpdate()

  rset = Some(pstmt.get.getGeneratedKeys)

  rset.get.next()

  id = Some(rset.get.getLong(1))
} finally {
  rset.foreach(_.close())
  pstmt.foreach(_.close())
}
```

The table structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE configuration_record (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  state TEXT,
  config_info JSONB
);
```

The exception thrown (which doesn't appear to be what the database throws, but what the statement proxy throws), looks like this:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: Java heap space 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:649)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
    at com.mohaine.db.SqlPrinterAbstract.getBindSqlString(SqlPrinterAbstract.java:49)
    at com.mohaine.db.PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.getBindSqlString(PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.java:120)
    at com.mohaine.db.PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.appendBindByIndex(PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.java:109)
    at com.mohaine.db.PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.bindSql(PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.java:85)
    at com.mohaine.db.PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.toString(PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.java:66)
    at data.SqlPrinter.outputSqlError(SqlPrinter.scala:79)
    at com.mohaine.db.PrintableStatementProxy.printError(PrintableStatementProxy.java:53)
    at com.mohaine.db.PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.executeUpdate(PrintablePreparedStatementProxy.java:379)...
```

Comment: `getBytes` (not specific to postgres) load all data in memory, so that's not surprising that for big `jsonData` is could raise memory issues ...

Comment: Suggestions on another way to change a string to an InputStream that doesn't use that method?

Comment: Use a JSON source that can be directly streamed